# Passing an arbitary lamba to a class method in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I wrote the following contrived code in order to explore some ideas and learn more about C++. What I have is an `Accountant class` which holds information about the accountant and an `Accountants class` which contains a vector of Accountants along with some methods.

The code also uses a lambda to find and print the `Accountants` that have a salary within a certain range.

What I'm trying to do is create a method that returns an `Accountants` object based on an arbitrary passed in lambda.

Code is below:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// just contains information about an Accountant
class Accountant
{
    private:
        std::string m_name;
        double m_salary;        // yes dealing with currency it's not good to use float types. I KNOW

    public:
        Accountant() {}
        Accountant( std::string _name, double _salary ) : m_name( _name ), m_salary( _salary ) {}
        double salary() const { return( m_salary ); }
        std::string name() const { return( m_name); }
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Accountant &accountant);     
};


std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Accountant &accountant)
{
    out << accountant.name() << " " << accountant.salary();
    return(out);
}


// contains a vector of Accountant and performs operations on them
class Accountants
{
    private:
        std::vector<Accountant> m_list;

    public:
        Accountants( std::vector<Accountant> list ) : m_list( list ) {}
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Accountants &m_list);

        // how to implement something like this?
        // 
        Accountants subset( .... some lambda ......   );
};


Accountants Accountants::subset(  .... some lambda .....)
{
    // perform std::find_if() with lambda has parameter and return an Accountants object.
    // what would be even better is have a way to more flexibly and
    // generically pass in lambda so almost any search criteria can be used to
    // return Accountants subset.
}


std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Accountants &list)
{
    std::vector<Accountant>::const_iterator iter = list.m_list.begin();

    while (iter != list.m_list.end())
    {
        out << *iter << std::endl;
        ++iter; 
    }
    return(out);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Accountant> emps{{"Josh",2100.0}, {"Kate", 2900.0}, {"Rose",1700.0}};
    Accountants list( emps );

    const auto min_wage = 0.0;
    const auto upper_limit = 2900.0;

    auto lambda = ([=]( Accountant &a ){ return (a.salary() >= min_wage && a.salary() < upper_limit); });


    std::cout << "List of Accountants" << std::endl  << list << std::endl;
    std::cout << "===============================================" << std::endl;


    std::vector<Accountant>::iterator items = std::find_if(emps.begin(), emps.end(), lambda );
    while( items != emps.end() )
    {
        std::cout << (*items).name() << " " << (*items).salary() << std::endl;
        items = std::find_if(++items, emps.end(), lambda );
    }


    // how to implement something like this?
    Accountants inRangeAccountants = list.subset( lambda );


    return( 0 );
}
```

What are the methods I could use, which code samples if possible, to create a method such as:

```
Accountants inRangeAccountants = list.subset( lambda );
```

such that "lambda" could be arbitrary? The idea is to be able to use the `subset()` method to return an `Accountants` object that contains items that much the search criteria specified in the lambda. Similar to what the code does in main() which returns the accountants within in certain salary range.

I'm thinking templates and std::function will need to be used?

Any help with code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use a template parameter, like the algorithms do for the optional callable objects.

Comment: What is the exact purpose of the `Accountants` class?

Comment: @dyp To group Accountant objects together and perform operation on them. It's a container class with methods.

Comment: So why doesn't the user of `Accountant` just use a container storing `Accountant`s directly?

Comment: I mean, if you have a `std::vector<Accountant> src`, you can easily write `std::vector<Accountant> dest; std::copy_if(begin(src), end(src), std::back_inserter(dest), [](Accountant const& e){ return some_condition(e); });` and even use different destination container types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `subset` function should take any kind of callable, so make it a member function template. Then use `copy_if` to copy the `Accountant`s that match the predicate to the result.

```
template<typename Callable>
Accountants subset(Callable&& c)
{
  std::vector<Accountant> result;
  std::copy_if(m_list.begin(), m_list.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(result), std::forward<Callable>(c));
  return result;
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b242072bcaaa30b3)

Comment: Is passing a function object by reference the new guideline? What happened to pass a function object by value?

Comment: @dyp Perfect forward all the things :) I honestly didn't think much before choosing this. But there is no downside to this, compared to passing by value, is there?

Comment: Beautiful dude respect.

Comment: Function objects are often small or even empty. If the compiler does not inline the function `subset`, you'll end up with an indirection, as far as I can tell. That indirection might be more costly than one copy/move that can often even be elided. (Stepanov, IIRC) -- edit: meh, well, `copy_if` takes by value so this point is moot.

Comment: Thank you for the code example. Very nice. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @dyp Optimizing perfect forwarding cases should be a big priority for any compiler worth its salt at this point.  And an empty function object may, at the worst, push a pointer around that is never read (as `operator()` can be found statically within `std::copy_if`).

Answer (score 4):

Could be as simple as:

```
template <typename Lambda>
Accountants subset(Lambda func)
{
    /* your code that calls func() */
}
```

You don't need to use `std::function` if all you're wanting is a lambda parameter value.  The code won't compile if you pass `subset` a parameter that cannot be called as a function.

Comment: This can be much more efficient than going to `std::function<...>` btw.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use `std::function<bool( const Account &)>` as the parameter. In this case you willl be abale to pass different lambdas.

For example

```
Accountants Accountants::subset( std::function<bool( const Account &)> f ) const;
```

And you can call the method for example the following way

```
Accounts a1( /* some arguments */ );

Accounts a2 = a1.subset( []( const Account &a ) { return a.salary() < 5000; } );
```

or

```
Accounts a2 = a1.subset( []( const Account &a ) { return a.name().front() == 'A'; } );
```

With std::function you may use functions, lambdas, functional objects. So there is no need to use a template.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe It is a declaration of a function type with an abstract declarator..

Comment: This was a novel syntax for me. What confused me was the expression inside the brackets, which seems to be only for template arguments.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe No, you can also use it e.g. in typedefs / type aliases. E.g. `using function_type = bool(const Account&); function_type my_function;`

Comment: Thanks, TIL. A lot more readable than the function pointer syntax. I''m guessing this was added with the lambdas?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe True, but it's not a function pointer. It's just a function. A function pointer: `using function_ptr_type = bool(*)(const Account&);` The syntax for the type is old, the syntax for the type alias is new.